# BTRFS going readonly with IO errors

Tags: usb-flash-drive, raspberry-pi, btrfs

I've got a Raspberry Pi 2B with 4 newly purchased 256GB USB flash drives attached. I set up the 4 drives as a RAID10 (data and metadata) btrfs volume. I've been trying to copy a very large (~35GB) file from another computer to this volume via rsync. The first time I did this, it spent 2 hours copying and the rsync progress info said 100%, but it then failed due to "readonly file system."

A bit of searching showed dmesg giving errors saying the volume was forced readonly due to `errno -5`:

```
[58463.350227] BTRFS: error (device sdd) in btrfs_commit_transaction:2071: errno=-5 IO failure (Error while writing out transaction)
[58463.352106] BTRFS info (device sdd): forced readonly
[58463.352120] BTRFS warning (device sdd): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
```

So I wondered if this one was a one-off thing:

```
# btrfs device stats /dev/sda
[/dev/sda].write_io_errs   3339
[/dev/sda].read_io_errs    0
[/dev/sda].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sda].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sda].generation_errs 0
# btrfs device stats /dev/sdb
[/dev/sdb].write_io_errs   3469
[/dev/sdb].read_io_errs    0
[/dev/sdb].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdb].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sdb].generation_errs 0
# btrfs device stats /dev/sdc
[/dev/sdc].write_io_errs   3601
[/dev/sdc].read_io_errs    2
[/dev/sdc].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdc].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sdc].generation_errs 0
# btrfs device stats /dev/sdd
[/dev/sdd].write_io_errs   4335
[/dev/sdd].read_io_errs    3
[/dev/sdd].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdd].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sdd].generation_errs 0
```

This seems quite a lot of IO errors, but the numbers are consistent across all 4 drives. Is this just what I should expect from USB flash drives? Every time I copy this file over it quickly forces my BTRfs volume readonly, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because it's a USB drive.  USB is notoriously unreliable on Linux for any kind of long-term usage, and the integrated hub and USB controller on the Pi are not particularly good, which just makes things worse.  The high write error counts corroborate this conclusion, the device will drop off the USB bus for some reason, but BTRFS never sees that that happened (because the block layer doesn't pass that info up properly), so it just keeps trying to write to the file and getting write errors back.

It's important to note that this can (and eventually will) result in potentially unrecoverable filesystem corruption.

As far as fixing it, start by unmounting the BTRFS volume (forcibly if you have to), and then disconnecting and reconnecting each flash drive in turn.  After doing this the filesystem should mount and run without issue (until the same issue inevitably happens again).

Comment: I was afraid of this :(